# Double Jumps of a Poisson Process

Tags: probability, measure-theory

If $N_t$ be a Poisson Process with rate $\lambda>0$, surely for any prescribed $t>0$, the probability that $N_t$ "jumps (at least) twice" at $t$ is zero, i.e. $\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow0}P\{N_t-N_{t-\epsilon}\geq 2\}=0$ (is this even a proper way to state what I want to say?)

Now my intuition tells me that the probability that $N_t$ "jumps twice" at *any* point in time should still be zero, but clearly you can't claim this by "integrating" zero over $t\in\mathbb{R}$ - that would be just like saying a uniform variable $X$ over $[0,1]$ has zero probability of being any point $t\in[0,1]$, and so $X$ has a zero probability of being in $[0,1]$. You would have to say, the probability of $X$ being in a small interval of length $dx$ is $1\cdot dx$, and the integral of that over $[0,1]$ is $1$.

Also I notice that the probability that $N_t$ "jumps at least once" at some point in time should be one, since that equivalent to the probability $\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}1-P\{N_t=0\} =1- e^{-\lambda t} = 1$. But again the probability of $N_t$ jumping at any $t>0$ is $0$.

The issue, I think, is me trying to claim you can sum probabilities over an uncountable set, when you actually have to do something like put a measure on the $t$'s. Can someone explain what's going on with a little more rigour than I in my best efforts have been able to muster here (shouldn't be hard)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The condition that $\mathbb P(N_{t+s}\geqslant N_t+2)=p(s)$ with $p(s)\ll s$ when $s\to0$ is usually included in the conditions defining a Poisson process. Call $D_t$ the event that a jump of $N$ before $t$ has size more than $1$. Then $D_t$ implies that $N_{kt/n}\geqslant N_{(k-1)t/n}+2$ for some $1\leqslant k\leqslant n$, hence $\mathbb P(D_t)\leqslant np(t/n)$. Since the RHS goes to $0$ when $n\to\infty$, this shows that $\mathbb P(D_t)=0$. Since this holds for every $t$, the probability that  a jump of $N$ has size more than $1$, ever, has probability $0$.

Comment: @Promothema Since you asked for the probability that $N_t$ jumps twice at any point in time: This event is given by $\cup_{n \geq 1} D_n$ and has probability zero since it's a countable union of sets of probability zero.

Comment: @saz No. You are misleading the OP. Please reread the definition of $D_t$.

Comment: I see, the first comment wasn't correct, sorry. But what's wrong about the other one? $\mathbb{P}[\exists t \geq 0: N_t \geq N_{t-}+2] = \mathbb{P} \left( \bigcup_n [\exists t \leq n: N_{t} \geq N_{t-}+2] \right) = \mathbb{P} \left( \bigcup_n D_n \right)=0$

Comment: To clarify: The condition $p(s)=o(s)$ as $s\to 0$ follows from $\mathbb{P}(N_s=k)=\frac{(s\lambda )^k}{k!}e^{-s\lambda}$, it's not an extra requirement.